# PHP newbie with a perplexing piece of code

Tags: php, mysql

this ought to be simple, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. i have tested it with good and bad passwords. no matter what, it will not go into the else statement. i am not sure what i am missing

my code:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "joeuser", "somepass", "testDB");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
  } else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM login_info";      
      $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

  if ($res) {
      while ($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          $id  = $newArray['first_name'];                          
          $testField = $newArray['last_name'];                      
          echo "The ID is ".$id." and the text is ".$testField."<br/>";
         }
  } else {
      printf("Could not retrieve records: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
  }

        mysqli_free_result($res);
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
  }
```

If i send it a user and password that do exist it does the if statement fine, but if i send it a test for one that is not in the db it still won't do the else? why?

Comment: Which if statement? the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
if ($res) {
      while ($newArray = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          $id  = $newArray['first_name'];                          
          $testField = $newArray['last_name'];                      
          echo "The ID is ".$id." and the text is ".$testField."<br/>";
         }
}

if (!isset($id)) {
      printf("Could not retrieve records: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Comment: Awesome! this worked, although I did try 
"if (empty($id))" and that didn't work, but 
"if (!isset($id))" work, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `MySQLi_Result` object.

A query is only not *successful* if some serious error occurred. Simply because a `SELECT` query didn't match any rows doesn't make the query unsuccessful. You'll still get a `MySQLi_Result` object back. You'll want to check with [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) whether the result set contains any rows.

BTW, save yourself some nesting:

```
if (!$something) {
    exit;
}

// continue as usual
```

No need for an `else` here, since you're `exit`ing anyway. Makes things simpler.

Comment: Although I prefer return over exit (hopefully the final code will use functions)